# How does it possible that $ZPP=RP\cap coRP$?

Tags: complexity-theory

How does it possible that $ZPP=RP\cap coRP$ ?
After all, it must be that $RP\cap coRP = \emptyset$
Where Am I wrong ?

Comment: What makes you think that their intersection is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity class P is obviously contained in their intersection (since the probability to err on either side is zero), so the intersection isn't empty.

(The complement of a complexity **class** isn't the same as the complement of a specific language.)